# php sql build $row-> variable

Tags: php, sql

I created a module showing some information stored in a database. I have a problem building a variable for a database query. In the mySQL database there are 3 field with following names:

description_lu

description_de

description_fr

I extract of the joomla installation the language code:

```
$myPageLang     = (explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

The result could be lu, de, fr.
Now I want to get the right description in the selected language shown while trying this code:

```
echo '$row->description_'.$myPageLang[1];
```

The right variable is printed to the display but is not executed.
Has anybody aou there a hint for me how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php would be the immediate “solution” to that particular problem. (The proper one would probably rather be to normalize the database.)

Comment: thanks, but I got this page several times and could not apply it to my case... I tried several combinations but got not the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
echo '$row->description_'.$myPageLang[1];
```

to

```
$desc='description_'.$myPageLang[1];
echo $row->$desc;
```

Comment: try this may be it will help you